# How many SKNodes on one scene? Why is my performance so bad?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am developing a card game, 52 cards, 20 are visible, the rest is on a "stack". There is no physics, nothing special, just SKSpriteNodes with PNG Images. I am running at 90% CPU on my iMAC and on an iPhone 5S it "feels" like one second until there is a reaction to touches. 
Is it a problem to have so many SKSpriteNodes on one scene? Or might the scaleFactor of .22 be the problem?

Where is my mistake?

Here I layout the cards

```
class PlayingCardView : SKSpriteNode {

    init(imageNamed: String, cardIndex: Int) {
        let cardTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageNamed)
        let cardScaleFactor:CGFloat = 0.22  
        let cardSize = CGSizeMake(cardTexture.size().width * cardScaleFactor,cardTexture.size().height * cardScaleFactor)
        super.init(texture: cardTexture, color: nil, size: cardSize)
        self.name = "\(cardIndex)"
    }
}

// MARK: UpdateUI
func updateUI() {
        assert(game.cards.count > 0, "No Cards")
        if status == GameIs.Paused {return}
        removeAllCards()
        PlayingCardViews.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        var scaleFactor:CGFloat = 0.8
        var upOffset:CGFloat = 0.0
        var cardsLeft = 0

        // create spritenotes for all 52 cards
        for i in 0..<game.cards.count {
            let card = game.cardAtIndex(i)
            // all cards until cardPositions.count face up. the rest on the stack
            var (x,y) = (7,6)
            if i<cardPositions.count {
                (x,y) = cardPositions[i]
            }
            // determine real position from the grid information
            let xPos:CGFloat = realXForPositionX(x)
            let yPos:CGFloat = realYForPositionY(y)
            let image =  backgroundImageForCard(card)
            // we save the currents positon in the Model
            card.positionGrid = (x,y)
            let cardSprite = PlayingCardView(imageNamed: backgroundImageForCard(card), cardIndex:i)
            PlayingCardViews.append(cardSprite) 
            if !card.removed {
                cardSprite.position = CGPointMake(realXForPositionX(x),realYForPositionY(y))  
                cardLayer.addChild(cardSprite)
                ++cardsLeft  
            }
        }
        if cardsLeft == 0 { gameOver(0, timeLeft: secondsLeft) }
    }
```

Comment: You should be able to have 52 sprites on the screen at the same time, but it depends on what you are doing with them. Do the performance problems start off right in the beginning when the scene  loads? and also how much memory are you using?

Comment: Yes, they start off right at the beginning. I don't do anything. Just awaiting a touch-event. Memory is around 100 MB

Comment: Where do you call the updateUI() method? WHow many nodes are being presented on the screen?

Comment: alltogether I have 63 nodes on the scene. This UIUpdate gets call when a touch-event occurs. I'm trying to strictly separate the Model from the View here, that's why, when a user interaction occurs, I change my model and then after everything is done (i.e. cards have been removed or replaced) I update the view.

Comment: Are you removing *all* the cards from the scene and adding them back each time the user touches the screen?

Comment: exactly. before the updateUI layouts the cards it removes all cards that have been added before. Therefore the Array PlayingCardViews is needed

Comment: I suggest you update only the card(s) that changed.

Comment: plus you will want to avoid creating (and allowing to dealloc) many sprites/textures at runtime. Preload all textures, create all sprites up front, reuse them. You have 52 cards and their textures, you can easily keep all that in memory at all times, and you know you have exactly 52 sprites at most as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just noticed it looks like you are adding all those sprites and setting up your scene in the Update method! You should just create a setup() { } method, add the sprites and setup in that, otherwise adding the cards gets called 60 times a second!

Call your custom setup method from didMoveToView (which is called only once) and then only call code to move or update the cards as is necessary for gameplay.

Comment: It's actually another method called updateUI, and not the overridden update method.

Comment: like ZeMoon says, it's a method that only gets called on a touch event. But I also noticed that my removing cards by doing a     func removeAllCards() {
        for playingCardView in PlayingCardViews {
            playingCardView.removeFromParent()
        }
    } is causing a 250ms delay !!